# What would be the best way to register the very first admin user in a Web Application?

Tags: security, web-applications, production-environment

So let's say a new Web Application is being deployed to production. In an enterprise system, more often than not, there is an Admin User pre-created, that will be used to log in to the system and then create the other admins and users. I was wondering what the best way would be to create this very first super admin user. We could create it via code on the first run, but that would mean at-least some one from the development team will have access to the credentials (developer / devOps / operations). Is there any way we could do it in such a way that no one but the Client/SuperAdmin of the system gets the credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the pre-created route is the best to take.
But another way will be to add a conditional in the admin registration logic.
By asking the supposed super admin what email he would be using, you should be able to assign the super admin role to him, if that condition is met.
Provided you have set up some kind of role properties in the database model for users, or maybe a full-fledged RBAC system (role-based access control)

(I am assuming the language is javascript (express and mongoose), though there would be a way to implement this in other languages):

```
// request response cycle
async (req, res) => {
//  destructure req body
const {name, email, password, role} = req.body
try {
    // check if user already exists
   let user = await User.findOne({email})
   if(user) {
       return res.status(400).json({errors: [{msg: 'Invalid registration 
details'}]})
   }
//    create new user in db
   user = new User({
       name,
       email,
       password,
       role
   })

// condition for assigning super admin role
if (email === 'super admin email address') {
  role === 'super admin'
}
```

The possibilities are endless depending on how you built your app.
I hope this will open up ideas for how you can solve this.

EDIT: Be sure to have created a hash function for the password, that way once the super admin registers, the password is immediately hashed and thus inaccessible.